# How to use Facebook SDK for Windows Phone 7 without handling Navigated event on some WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm following some examples from 
[Facebook SDK for .NET](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/) specifically the ones for Windows Phone.

I don't want to create a WebBrowser control in my xaml since I saw that in the Library  there is already a `LoginPage` that contains a `WebBrowser` control.

I don't understand why in their [example](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-windows-phone-sample/blob/master/src/facebook-windows-phone-sample/Pages/FacebookLoginPage.xaml) they create another `WebBrowser` control to handle the login, and in the code behind they handle the `Navigated` event.

I would like to have some cleaner handling of `Login` and retrieving basic info from the logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

To replace all those lines that you see in the example, you could simply do:

```
var client = new FacebookSessionClient(appId);
var Session = await client.LoginAsync("basic_info,publish_actions,read_stream,user_photos");
```

Use the `client` and the `Session` you created before to make other calls to Facebook.

Example:

```
string path = "me?fields=name,picture";
var res = await client.GetTaskAsync(path, new Dictionary<string, object>());
```

You have a `JsonObject` with the result.